# search and copy files from a directory structure by reading a text file

Tags: windows, recursive

I have a folder with many subfolders and files in them. I have a text file with the names of the files that I want copied to a separate destination folder. The filenames in the text file do not have path information.

In the destination folder, I want the file and its folder structure recreated. Is there a quick script for that? or a tool? I'm on Windows.

Comment: Starting point for you to build on but this is trivial for a batch scripter like myself.... `FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=*" %A IN ("C:\Folder\Path\TextFile.txt") DO ECHO %~A`. . . https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html . . . Read over some of my answer that may be applicable just pick some and read as I'm sure I've helped with this before for someone: https://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A510662+body%3A+for+%2Ff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following PowerShell script should do what you want.

Change the first three variables to fit your environment.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\06\28\SU_1334840.ps1
#Requires -Version 3

# get files to copy from file in same foler
$FileList = Get-Content '.\FileList.txt'
$BaseSrc = 'X:\Source\path\'
$BaseDst = 'Y:\Destination\path\'

ForEach ($File in $FileList){
   ForEach ($Find in (Get-ChildItem $BaseSrc$File -File -Recurse)) {
       $DestFile = Join-Path $BaseDst ($Find.FullName.Replace($BaseSrc,'') )
       $DestDir = Split-Path $DestFile
       If (!(Test-Path $DestDir)){ MD $DestDir |Out-Null}
       # "Copying {0} to {1}" -f $Find.FullName,$DestFile
       Copy-Item $Find.FullName $DestFile
    }
}
```

To see what's going on while the script works, remove the `#` before `"Copying...`

The script requires at least PowerShell version 3

Depending on the size of your list / the number of files and subdirs in your source tree, this a bit different approach may be faster.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\06\28\SU_1334840_2.ps1
#Requires -Version 3

# get files to copy from file in same foler
$FileList = Get-Content '.\FileList.txt'
$BaseSrc = 'X:\Source\path\'
$BaseDst = 'Y:\Destination\path\'

ForEach ($File in (Get-ChildItem $BaseSrc -File -Recurse)) {
    If ($File.Name -in $FileList) {
       $DestFile = Join-Path $BaseDst ($File.FullName.Replace($BaseSrc,'') )
       $DestDir = Split-Path $DestFile
       If (!(Test-Path $DestDir)){ MD $DestDir |Out-Null}
       "Copying {0} to {1}" -f $File.FullName,$DestFile
       Copy-Item $File.FullName $DestFile
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
> . Q:\Test\2018\06\28\SU_1334840.ps1
Copying C:\sys\7z.dll to A:\Test\sys\7z.dll
Copying C:\sys\7z.exe to A:\Test\sys\7z.exe
Copying C:\sys\ClipBoard.exe to A:\Test\sys\ClipBoard.exe
Copying C:\sys\ClipBoard.txt to A:\Test\sys\ClipBoard.txt
Copying C:\sys\DUMPHEX.EXE to A:\Test\sys\DUMPHEX.EXE
```

Comment: this works, for some reason the script doesn't find some files like " 00-00-00_0001 0894 0007861.JPG". Is there way to list which files were not found? (Do you notice the space between opening inverted commas and the first 0 in that file name?!

Comment: We found a solution for such files. We prepended all filesnames in the text file with a *. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for feedback, just out of interrest - which variant was faster in your tries?

Comment: The first one was better in fact and I ended up using it! I have about 17k filenames in the FileList.txt and machine is a 16G RAM, Win 2012 Server.

Comment: Wow, from that numbers I would have expected the latter one leading, but file server caching seems to turn it.

Comment: You're right! My apologies. We'd tried with a sample file much smaller earlier. Indeed the second script is much faster than the first. :) Thanks again. [There was a problem though. We'd pre-pended * in all filenames. The second script doesn't like those stars, it doesn't produce any output. So we reverted the files list.]

Comment: @Regmi I tried using this script to copy mp3 files and it didn't copy anything. In my BaseSrc folder, the file names have the following structure: "Artist name - Song name" eg. `Chic - Good Times (Dj 'S' Bootleg` in my List.txt file has only the name of the song, eg. `Good Times (Dj 'S' Bootleg`, how to copy ignoring the artist name using only the music name. Another problem is that in addition to espace in the name of the song, there are also special characters like `(` `' '`.