# Copy audio files from multiple subfolders to another folder using List.txt file

Tags: windows, powershell-5.0

My Powershell version is 5.1.19041.1645

I want to copy audio files from several folders to another folder using the txt files where the song names in the List.txt file have a different structure than the song names in the original folder.

I used the link as an example:
[search-and-copy-files-from-a-directory](https://superuser.com/questions/1334840/search-and-copy-files-from-a-directory-structure-by-reading-a-text-file)

I tried:

```
$files = 'C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\List.txt'
$location = 'C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\Select Dance\'
$destination = 'C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\Select Dance Copy\'

Get-ChildItem $location -Filter *.mp3 |
Foreach-Object {  
  $content = $_.Name
  $pos = $content.IndexOf("-")
  $artistPart = $content.Substring(0, $pos)
  $musicPart = $content.Substring($pos+2)

  $pos2 = $musicPart.IndexOf(".")
  $musileft = $musicPart.Substring(0, $pos2)

  If ($pos2 -lt 36) {
    $leng=$pos2
  } else {
    $leng=$pos2-($pos2-36)
  } 

  $musicNameRight = $musileft.Substring(0, $leng)  
}     
gc $files | % {
                   
    $result = gci -Recurse $location$musicNameRight $_
            
    if($result) {
        write-host -ForegroundColor Green "found $_ in $location!"
        write-host "copying $_ to $destination..."
        copy-item $result.FullName $destination\$_
    }
}
```

In Foreach-Object I managed to eliminate from the original name ($location), the parts that are different, `Artist Name -`  and `.mp3`, from the names in the List.txt ($files), but I can't get the script to compare the files using the information from the `$musicNameRight` variable.

The song name contained in the "$files" path:
`Good Times (Dj 'S' Bootleg CMG Dance`

The song name contained in the "$location" path:
`Chic - Good Times (Dj 'S' Bootleg CMG Dance Re Mix).mp3`

How to make the script use the correct information of the names that are in the variable `$musicNameRight`?

Note:
I defined `$musicPart.Substring(0, 36)`, because all song names in the List.txt file are limited to 36 characters. They will never have more than that.

Comment: @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style The script doesn't generate any output because the names in the list.txt and in the source folder have different structures, that's why I'm trying, inside the Foreach-Object. make the suitability of the name in the source folder so that they have the same structure and the script works when it finds some equivalence between the information and copy the file corresponding to the list.

Comment: @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style The contents of List.txt and the folder where the files  are in my question, haven't you seen it?... or did I misunderstand your question?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding you just need to make simple adjustments to the `gci` variable parameter values to suffice for making minimal changes to your existing logic.

- Rather than using `$result = gci -Recurse $location$musicNameRight $_`
- Use `$result = gci -Recurse "$location*$_*"` instead

Add a trailing and a leading single asterisk to `$_` will work as a wildcard with the `Get-ChildItem` command to bring back the result of all matching files recursively which it finds. Also enclose the concatenated variables including those asterisks in double quotes (i.e. `"$location*$_*"`).

### PowerShell (Option 1)

```
$files = 'C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\List.txt'
$location = 'C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\Select Dance\'
$destination = 'C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\Select Dance Copy\'

Get-ChildItem $location -Filter *.mp3 | % {
    $musicNameRight = $_.Basename.Split("-")[1].Trim();
    If ($musicNameRight.Length -gt 36) {$musicNameRight = $musicNameRight.Substring(0, 36)};
    };

Get-Content $files | % {               
    $result = Get-ChildItem -Recurse "$location*$_*" 
    If($result) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "found $_ in $location!"
        Write-Host "copying $_ to $destination..."
        Copy-Item $result.FullName -Destination $destination\$($_.Name)
    }
};
```

---

## A different approach

Using `split` with dash (`-`) as the delimiter, index `[1]` will provide the same result as the `substrings`. I also believe you do not need to use the `list.txt` at all nor the `get-content` command.

Using the wildcards around the `$musicNameRight` variable, I moved the `$result` using that into the same `foreach-object` loop to perform the conditional copy from there. It is safe to leave the extension with the variable there for the preferred destination file name.

**Note:** If you are after the original name with the name and the song artist name and song name plus extension, use the `copy-item` beneath the conditional `If()` instead that is commented out in the script (i.e. `Copy-Item $result.FullName -Destination $destination\$_;`).

### PowerShell (Option 2)

```
$location = 'C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\Select Dance\';
$destination = 'C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\Select Dance Copy\';

Get-ChildItem $location -Filter *.mp3 |
Foreach-Object {  
  $musicNameRight = "$($_.Basename.Split("-")[1])$($_.Extension)".Trim();
  
  $result = gci -Recurse "$location*$musicNameRight*";
  If ($result) {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Found $_ in $location!";
    Write-Host "Copying $_ to $destination...";
    Copy-Item $result.FullName -Destination $destination\$musicNameRight;
    ##Copy-Item $result.FullName -Destination $destination\$_;
    };

}
```

---

## Supporting Resources

- [Get-ChildItem](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html)

  > **Wildcards**
  >
  > When listing a single folder (without recursion), you can do
  > `get-childitem c:\music\*.mp3` Unlike the CMD shell, in PowerShell the
  > path filter of `c:\music\*.mp3` is applied only to files not folders (or
  > other containers).
  >
  > To apply a wildcard recursively to a whole tree of items in PowerShell
  > add the `-recurse` parameter: `get-childitem c:\music\*.mp3 -recurse`
  >
  > or more explicitly:
  > `get-childitem c:\music\ -filter *.mp3 -recurse`
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [Split()](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)

  > **Key**
  >
  > `strSeparator`  The character used to split up each string, by
  > default whitespace (space/newline/tab)
- [Trim()](https://ss64.com/ps/trim.html)

  > By default `trim()` will remove leading and trailing spaces and leading and trailing line breaks.
- [If()](https://ss64.com/ps/if.html)
- [String.Length Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.length?view=net-6.0)
- [Comparison Operators](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-compare.html)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136125/discussion-on-answer-by-vomit-it-chunky-mess-style-copy-audio-files-from-multi).